# Install linux from parition instead of usb?

Tags: partition, system-installation

I'm running Xubuntu and don't have a usb or CD available but want to replace my OS with Manjaro.

Is it possible to create a new disk partition and then use that as a media device for installing the OS?

What would the process be for doing this?

Comment: Most posts I can find about this are related to grub2, they won't "just work" with uefi systems. EG: http://opensourceforu.com/2009/03/install-linux-straight-from-an-iso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dump the iso image on partition with:

```
dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Then, make the partition bootable (with gparted, parted or fdisk) and move it in order boot to first position.

Comment: Thx will try at home tonight and mark correct once working